# Obtaining adjusted (predicted) proportions with lme4 - using the glmer-function

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I aim to estimate the annual proportion of patients (% of patients) that are smokers in a population whose age and sex must be taken into account. In other words, I want to calculate the adjusted prevalence (%) of smoking each year. I have repeated measurements on the same individuals and want to model the individual as a random effect, which is why I use the lme4 package, more precisely the glmer function. The variable of main interest is "year" (period 1996 to 2014), which I need to model as a fixed effect.

**Aim:** Obtain adjusted proportions (%) of smokers each year.

Suppose the data set is named "df" and the year variable is converted to a factor.

I tried this code (*generated with a slightly different data set than the attached one*) to fit the model:

```
> smoke <- glmer(smoker ~ biomarker + year + sex + age + (1 | id), data
> = df, family = binomial, nAGQ = 1)

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -6.201632   0.231582 -26.779  < 2e-16 ***
biomarker        -0.015364   0.008299  -1.851  0.06413 .  
yuar1997           0.648292   0.212400   3.052  0.00227 ** 
yuar1998          -0.586996   0.227217  -2.583  0.00978 ** 
yuar1999          -1.194309   0.216907  -5.506 3.67e-08 ***
yuar2000          -0.999889   0.217536  -4.596 4.30e-06 ***
yuar2001          -0.884453   0.203351  -4.349 1.37e-05 ***
yuar2002          -0.777464   0.199151  -3.904 9.47e-05 ***
yuar2003          -0.961869   0.194723  -4.940 7.83e-07 ***
yuar2004          -1.755470   0.197157  -8.904  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2005          -1.207833   0.189753  -6.365 1.95e-10 ***
yuar2006          -1.072532   0.187504  -5.720 1.07e-08 ***
yuar2007          -1.494477   0.189467  -7.888 3.08e-15 ***
yuar2008          -2.441916   0.191069 -12.780  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2009          -1.881562   0.187321 -10.045  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2010          -2.254924   0.187254 -12.042  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2011          -1.634935   0.184929  -8.841  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2012          -2.405588   0.187349 -12.840  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2013          -2.119775   0.186729 -11.352  < 2e-16 ***
yuar2014          -2.241768   0.210259 -10.662  < 2e-16 ***
sex              -0.071377   0.115975  -0.615  0.53826    
age              -0.012897   0.008011  -1.610  0.10742
```

Using the predict function to obtain probability of being a smoker in 2005:

```
predict(smoke, data.frame(age=mean(df$age), year="2005", sex=mean(df$sex), biomarker=mean(df$biomarker, na.rm=T)), type="response", re.form = NA)
```

I obtain much too low probabilities of being a smoker a particular year:

```
0.0002233488
```

The same is true when using the lsmeans and effects package. Figures should be around 5–15% smokers.

**In short**, in the data set I'm aiming to obtain the proportions of smokers during different years, adjusted for differences in age, sex and the biomarker while accounting of repeated measurements.

I'd be extremely grateful for a solution to these problems.

Comment: One thing I noticed was the large variance in your random intercept, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q3/018862.html) for some info.

Comment: In what sense were the values implausible?

Comment: The prevalence was around 3% which is far to low, as roughly 10% should be smoking.

Comment: I interpreted the predicted estimates as a prevalence of 3%  if the estimate was 0,03. I did not transform 0,03. Using regular logistic regression returned more plausible proportions... I'm not sure if I'm doing this the proper way...

Comment: Why don't you add the `summary()` of your model and your interpretation?

Comment: Thanks for the replies above, but I still haven't solved the problem. @allexforrence: hmmmm, I'm not sure what You mean. I'm familiar with the summary()-function but how will that help me obtaining the desired proportions?

Comment: It makes it easier for other folks to eyeball your results and understand your thought process. Did you read about complete separation at all?

Comment: I did read about it, but I came to the conclusion that I should not have a problem with that, but you might have come to the opposite conclusion, and in that case I'm likely to be wrong. But crude prevalence is around 10%, adjusted prevalence with logistic regression (without mixed effects) is around 10% (using the average of smoking each year for each individual). The 3% obtaiend from the glmer seem to far away from that...

Comment: working on this. `nAGQ=0` is very inaccurate, but I don't think that's the proximal problem.  Maybe Jensen's inequality ... also, `lattice::qqmath(ranef(<fitted_model>, condVar=TRUE))` looks interesting/problematic ...

Comment: [correction] Thanks for the info prof Bolker. I use nAGQ=0 to speed up calculations but changing it to 1 (which might still be low) did not materially affect the results but took 2 hours to compute. If the qq-plot worried you, then it worried me too =). I'm still stuck though; unfortunately very few hits on google with this problem.

Comment: Some general observations: biomarker enters  your model as a continuous variable.  Can it truly assume any value (including non integers) or should it be a factor or random effect?  Age is also continuous; are you expecting/testing a directional change w/ age? could you fit a more flexible function (age^2, use gamm).  Your intercept (eg 1996) has a very small coefficient; inv.logit(-6.20)  = 0.002 is very small & most of your other coefficient are negative.  Sounds like the model takes a long time to run, but can you simplify it & try to get more sensical results?

Comment: @ N Brouwer: Thanks for the remarks. Biomarker should enter the model as a continuous variable (which is preferable in this particular case). Actually I did not try any polynomials for age, or any other variable as the cohort is fairly homogenous in terms of age and biomarker. However, I haven't thought about GAMM's but perhaps I should try that. Would it be computationally more burdensome? I'm reading the gamm4-manual atm. Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about your reply, N Brouwer; perhaps I should boil it all down to 1 observation for each individual each year. That would do it computationally much simpler and still be fairly valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

predict() in lme4 does not work well unless the grouping factor specification is "realistic". If we use samples from the observed data, we get reasonable predictions. I think this is a bug in predict.merMod()

This is lme4 1.1-7

```
my.fit <- glmer(smoker ~ biomarker + year + sex + age + (1|id), data = df, family = binomial(link='logit'), nAGQ = 0)
## predict with the observed data
predictions <- predict(my.fit, type = "response")
mean(predictions, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.1144976
## predict for year 1996 to year 2014
new.df <- df[sample(nrow(df), replace = TRUE), ]
sapply(1996:2014, function(x) {
  new.df$year <- x
  predictions <- predict(my.fit, newdata = new.df, type = "response", allow.new.levels=TRUE)
  mean(predictions, na.rm = TRUE)
})
[1] 0.15785350 0.15374013 0.14974742 0.14586612 0.14208791 0.13840528 0.13481145 0.13130033
[9] 0.12786645 0.12450488 0.12121121 0.11798144 0.11481198 0.11169959 0.10864132 0.10563448
[17] 0.10267662 0.09976548 0.09689897
```

Compare that with what you get if you set id to a new value, not present in df when my.fit was evaluated.

```
new.df$id <- 1
    sapply(1996:2014, function(x) {
      new.df$year <- x
  predictions <- predict(my.fit, newdata = new.df, type = "response", allow.new.levels=TRUE)
  mean(predictions, na.rm = TRUE)
})
[1] 0.07292960 0.06660550 0.06079003 0.05544891 0.05054904 0.04605868 0.04194759 0.03818706
[9] 0.03475000 0.03161093 0.02874596 0.02613281 0.02375069 0.02158030 0.01960378 0.01780458
[17] 0.01616745 0.01467832 0.01332425
```

If you want confidence intervals around the predicted means, I can recommend the `boot` package

```
my.bootstrap.predictions.f <- function(data, indices){
  return(mean(predict(my.fit, newdata = data[indices, ], type = "response", allow.new.levels=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE))
}
## predict for year 1996 to year 2014
new.df <- df[sample(nrow(df), replace = TRUE), ]
time.period <- 1996:2014
my.results <- matrix(nrow=length(time.period), ncol = 4)
for(x in 1:length(time.period)){
  my.results[x, 1] <- time.period[x]
  new.df$year <- time.period[x]
  ## bootstrap using a realistic number of samples per year, say 20000
  my.boot.obj <- boot(data = new.df[sample(nrow(new.df), 20000, replace = TRUE), ], statistic = my.bootstrap.predictions.f, R = 100)
  my.results[x, 2] <- my.boot.obj[[1]]
  my.results[x, 3:4] <- quantile(my.boot.obj[[2]], c(0.025, 0.975))
}
colnames(my.results) <- c("Year", "mean proportion", "lower.ci", "upper.ci")
```

Using R = 2 in the call to `boot`, I got the following results:

```
my.results
      Year mean proportion   lower.ci   upper.ci
 [1,] 1996      0.15546203 0.15074711 0.15913858
 [2,] 1997      0.15259172 0.15187967 0.15367255
 [3,] 1998      0.14850053 0.14672908 0.14758575
 [4,] 1999      0.14304792 0.14076788 0.14285565
 [5,] 2000      0.14340505 0.14308830 0.14354602
 [6,] 2001      0.13575446 0.13580401 0.13906530
 [7,] 2002      0.13378345 0.13092585 0.13734706
 [8,] 2003      0.13135301 0.13367143 0.13379709
 [9,] 2004      0.12884709 0.12817521 0.12889604
[10,] 2005      0.12407854 0.12164363 0.12338582
[11,] 2006      0.11703560 0.11692974 0.12129822
[12,] 2007      0.11701868 0.11660557 0.12143424
[13,] 2008      0.11427061 0.11247954 0.11578390
[14,] 2009      0.10743174 0.10681350 0.11119430
[15,] 2010      0.10769067 0.10547794 0.10833410
[16,] 2011      0.10677037 0.10734999 0.10867513
[17,] 2012      0.10064624 0.09991072 0.10205153
[18,] 2013      0.09735750 0.09704462 0.10003968
[19,] 2014      0.09448228 0.09331708 0.09346973
```

Comment: Many thanks Hans. Could You please explain the results? I'm looking for the predicted proportions each year from the first to the last year.

Comment: I'll expand the answer.

Comment: Thats absolutely beautiful! Is there any easy way to get the confidence interval/standard error for the predictions? Regardless, MANY MANY THANKS!!!!

Comment: I'll have a go at that too.

Comment: I appreciate Your valuable time Hans. Problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks Adam! This is actually the first time I have used `boot` in this context, so perhaps you should verify with a knowledgeable person that this use of `boot` is proper.

And don't forget to refit the model with nAGQ = 1 or even nAGQ = 2.

Comment: Is this a bug in `predict.merMod()`, or is it a fundamental issue with back-transforming linear predictions without accounting for variance (i.e. a Jensen's inequality problem)?  In either case, if you think this is a serious issue that should be addressed in the code or in the documentation, could you post an issue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues ?

Comment: I failed tried to replicate this behaviour with another data set (I ran glmer on a dichotomized version of the sleepstudy), so I don't know what to think now.

I'll revisit Adam's data and try to figure out when predict() make bad predictions.

Comment: When predicting from the fit produced above, the predictions are way off (0.025) whenever the original ids are not used, as in:

1. omitting the ids completely and giving re.form = NA to predict()

2. using new ids.

If I change half of the ids to new ones, the mean prediction becomes 0.07.

The reasonable prediction is about 0.11

The mean of the random intercept is, if course, 0, but the predictions appear to work as if this mean would be greater than zero (because when they are left out, the predictions decrease).

Comment: Ben, I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/281

Answer (score 3):

To get the confidence interval, you could also try the `effects` package

```
lmer.1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
library("effects")
# obtain a fit at different estimates of the predictor
ef.1=effect(c("Days"),lmer.1)
df.ef=data.frame(ef.1)
df.ef
plot(effect(c("Days"),lmer.1),grid=TRUE)
```

here is fitted value and the CI. The width of the CI bands increases because the model was a random slope model.

```
   Days      fit        se    lower    upper
1    0 251.4051  6.824557 237.9377 264.8726
2    2 272.3397  7.094226 258.3401 286.3393
3    4 293.2742  8.555537 276.3909 310.1576
4    6 314.2088 10.732292 293.0299 335.3877
5    8 335.1434 13.277148 308.9425 361.3443
```

[image: Confidence Interval Bands]

If you were to use a random intercept only model like this (as in your example),

```
lmer.1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

you shall get parallel CI bands